# How to downgrade react-native

Tags: android, reactjs, typescript, react-native, mobile

My project configured with react-native version 0.72. Suddenly my react-native version was upgraded to version 0.73.

I need to downgrade the react-native version. because im working on openjdk 11. but the version 0.73 was supported to openjdk 17.

appreciate your solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your package.json and package-lock.json (or yarn.lock) checked into version control, then simply:

1. revert those files to an earlier version
2. delete your `node_modules` directory
3. run `npm install`

BTW: have you considered using Expo rather than RN CLI?  Even the RN team recommends Expo's use.  Expo would be upgrading your RN version when it has been tested and is appropriate.  And using the EAS build cloud service, your builds are not a hostage to whatever software gets installed onto your development machine, be it Android Studio, JDKs, XCode, cocoapods, operating system updates, etc.